# ActiveRecord where method call optimisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a piece of code witch looks like this:

```
Post.all.reject {|p| p.created_at.beginning_of_month != params[:date].to_date}
```

Is there a method to write the same code using where method and to not get all elements?

Comment: what is you rails version ? and your DB ? and most importantly, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: rails 3.2.14 and mysql

Comment: If i understand well, you're trying to select all posts not created at a certain month ?

Comment: yes, absolutely right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `where`, I'd go by:

```
# x-month being a date from your desired month.
# .. defines the range between the beginning and the end
Post.where(:created_at => x-month.beginning_of_month..x-month.end_of_month)
```

Comment: +1 - hey, nice solution. Actually you'd have to use `not` to match OP's expectations

Comment: Yea you're right... And that only comes with rails 4... Haha, then we'd have to use sql again `where("...")` :/

Comment: possible with arel in rails < 4, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no database-agnostic solution to this, because you need to extract the month from the date. So, in raw SQL you would have :

```
date = params[:date].to_date
Post.where("MONTH(created_at) != ? AND YEAR(created_at) = ?", [date.month, date.year])
```

Now it is possible to cheat a bit with normalization in order to use a db-agnostic solution.
Just add some `created_at_month` and `created_at_year` columns to your model, along with this callback :

```
after_create :denormalize_created_at
def denormalize_created_at
  assign_attributes created_at_month: created_at.month, 
                    created_at_year:  created_at.year
  save validate: false 
end
```

Now you can do:

Rails < 4 :

```
date = params[:date].to_date
Post
  .where(Post.arel_table[:created_at_month].not_eq date.month)
  .where(created_at_year: date.year)
```

Rails 4+ :

```
date = params[:date].to_date
Post.not(created_at_month: date.month).where(created_at_year: date.year)
```

Comment: This is a great workaround if you need these queries more often. For a one-time use it's a bit too much to set up. :)

Comment: yup. It's just that i tend to prefer DB-agnostic solutions... and with an index on those columns, it may sometimes perform better.

Answer (score 3):

mysql has a `MONTH` function to get the month of a datetime column.

```
 Post.where("MONTH(created_at) != ?", params[:date].to_date.month)
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution to include the NOT in MySQL